# Jasper creating a bar chart for each series variable

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I am creating a report that requires multiple barcharts to track what user is going to which page based on user role.

Each role is its own series, however when I run the report I am getting the correct data but each series is making its own bargraph

I.E I have two search pages A and B

A public user goes to A 5 times and B twice
an Admin goes to B 2 times and B 9 times

the report would create 4 reports: public/A, public/B, admin/A,admin/B

However the chart should be public and admin on the same chart for A and one more for B

Any ideas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2018-08-17T13:07:36 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="DEL_sys_usg_rpt_bar" pageWidth="576" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="536" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true" uuid="c90df0e9-ca70-4aa8-88ab-3cc66cad2ade">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter (2)"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="inch"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="false"/>
    <parameter name="START_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="END_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="START_DATE_RPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="END_DATE_RPT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SCREENS" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <parameter name="Q1START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q1END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q2START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q2END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q3START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q3END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q4START" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="Q4END" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
t.qtr,
t.url_txt as url_txt,
sum(t.role0) as role0_page,
sum(t.role1) as role1_page,
sum(t.role2) as role2_page,
sum(t.role3) as role3_page,
sum(t.role4) as role4_page,
t.user_role_txt as user_role_txt
from 
(
                SELECT 
               $P{Q1START} as qtr,
                url_txt,
                user_role_txt,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role0'  then 1 else 0 end as role0,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role1' then 1 else 0 end as role1,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role2' then 1 else 0 end as role2,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role3'  then 1 else 0 end as role3,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role4'  then 1 else 0 end as role4
                from table
                where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q1START}
                AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q1END}     
                 AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}
UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                $P{Q2START} as qtr,
                url_txt,
                user_role_txt,
                                   CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role0'  then 1 else 0 end as role0,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role1' then 1 else 0 end as role1,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role2' then 1 else 0 end as role2,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role3'  then 1 else 0 end as role3,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role4'  then 1 else 0 end as role4                    from table
                where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q2START}
                AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q2END}     
                 AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}
UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                $P{Q3START} as qtr,
                url_txt,
                user_role_txt,
                                   CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role0'  then 1 else 0 end as role0,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role1' then 1 else 0 end as role1,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role2' then 1 else 0 end as role2,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role3'  then 1 else 0 end as role3,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role4'  then 1 else 0 end as role4                    from table
                where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q3START}
                AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q3END}     
                 AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}
UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                $P{Q4START} as qtr,
                url_txt,
                user_role_txt,
                                   CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role0'  then 1 else 0 end as role0,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role1' then 1 else 0 end as role1,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role2' then 1 else 0 end as role2,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role3'  then 1 else 0 end as role3,
                CASE when user_role_txt = 'Role4'  then 1 else 0 end as role4                    from table
                where acs_ts::date >= $P{Q4START}
                AND acs_ts::date <= $P{Q4END}     
                 AND $X{IN,url_txt,SCREENS}
) as t
group by t.qtr, t.url_txt,t.user_role_txt]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="url_txt" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="role0_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="role1_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="role2_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="role3_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="role4_page" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="user_role_txt" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="qtr" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <group name="Group1" keepTogether="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{url_txt}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="98" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="t_4" mode="Opaque" x="130" y="-1" width="320" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="70d07b08-a98f-462f-912c-86e8ca3cffa5">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h1" value="full"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DEL Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="([GENERAL])" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="COMPUTE_5" mode="Opaque" x="140" y="15" width="300" height="15" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="fa243ebd-82b3-426a-8693-995a1d029d8c">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h1" value="full"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Data Element Library Usage Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="DATE_1" mode="Opaque" x="430" y="0" width="102" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="8c30e5fd-4921-4b61-a07d-fec225f73dca">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2" value="full"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Run Date:  " + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="PAGE_1" mode="Opaque" x="430" y="12" width="40" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d3278171-f2e1-4241-b57f-5e4f3fc2ee09">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2" value="start"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="PAGE_1" mode="Transparent" x="470" y="12" width="30" height="12" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f12aa9ee-4dbb-4569-bad4-1994dcfc045c">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h2" value="end"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="150" height="56" uuid="5c21389e-0147-4bab-8b2b-b2462883c4e4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{CMSLOGO_DIR} + "CMS_logo.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
                <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="280" height="12" uuid="9f93ebb5-6ca9-4f7f-be7c-d06093207859">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.tag.h3" value="start"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Note: * indicates an empty value.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="140" y="30" width="300" height="20" uuid="c2b0287c-ce1e-461c-aabb-1c6e28b0b30d"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["From "+$P{START_DATE_RPT}+" to "+$P{END_DATE_RPT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="285">
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true">
                    <reportElement key="" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="19" width="480" height="245" uuid="55b46114-7361-48b7-8dac-5c40089efb33">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="inch"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <chartTitle position="Top">
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA[$F{url_txt}]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend position="Right"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset incrementType="Page"/>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Role0"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{role0_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Role1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{role1_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Role2"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{role2_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Role3"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{role3_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["Role4"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{qtr}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{role4_page}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Quarter"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Page Count"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

EDIT: I have gotten all the series on the same chart, fixed due to the different variable name

Comment: It's difficult to understand all your data, but as report is structured you need as many records as you expect chart. The detail band iterates on each record, hence it creates a chart

Comment: What band would you reccomend then? Since I have to pull the url_txt information from the db for each chart. And its a variable amount of charts per report

Comment: I can't really understand all your queries, the detail band is ok, but you need to create the query so you get the number of charts needed, then probably you need subreports to display the chart (hence a new query for chat data, where you use the summary band), but once again all the info is a bit to much for me to comprehend at this moment :)

Comment: Hi there @PetterFriberg , there is an update to this story with different attempts with so solution. If you could look at it that would be amazing thanks :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084723/jaspersoft-barchart-seperating-charts-by-category